# How to pass String value from a app to php web service using android volley

Tags: java, php, android, http-post, android-volley

I want to implement a search feature in my app.i.e. I want to print to some specific data according to user input as string.

here is my java code:

```
 JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.optString("fullname"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.optString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(obj.optString("location"));

                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("id"));

                        movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

               });
                        }


                        adapter.reloadData();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        })

        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("fullname", "test");// this is variable and hardcoded passed value for testing

                return params;
            }
        }
            ;

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    header("content-type:application/json");
    require_once("dbConnect.php");

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
         if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];


    $sql = "SELECT id ,image,fullname,location from uploadfinding WHERE fullname like '%$fullname%'";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($result, array(

                "id"=>$row["id"],
                "fullname"=>$row["fullname"],
                "image"=>$row['image'],
                "location"=>$row["location"]));

                //echo " over";

        }


    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($result));
    fclose($fp);            
    echo json_encode($result);

    mysqli_close($conn);
         }
    }
    ?>
```

I'm using volley library and I'm trying to pass a hard coded value in the variable and trying to use it on php code like this:

```
 params.put("fullname", "test");//here fullname is variable and test is hardcoded  value
```

but that hard coded passed value in the variable didn't get in php variable (with same name),that's why desired input not saved in php variable and my search is not working. So how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `to pass a hard coded value in the variable`. You think you don't have to tell about which variable you are talking? `didn't get in php variable `. You think you dont have to tell which variable ?

Comment: please see my updated code , have U need any other info?

Comment: You should let the php script echo always some json text. Now you are not doing that if one of the 'if's does not come true.

Comment: And you should not try with the insert during first tests. Just make a php script that echos some predefined json to see if you can receive it. Concentrate on echoing the variable value.

Comment: `How to perform search in android app using php script`. Pretty bad description of your problem. You do not know how to post a value to a webserver i would think.

Comment: yes.. Till now I'm using webservices that are works like above code@greenapps.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a JsonArrayRequest. But your php script is for a normal POST request.

Comment: yes I know it but my json response is a array of objects.When I'm trying to change it need string request .and string request didn't print my response structure

Comment: What is printed by `Log.d(TAG, response.toString());` ? You should have told before.

Comment: it prints nothing @greenapps

Comment: Indeed. As the script does not echo anything if things go wrong. I said that before. You know what you have to do first.

Comment: `and string request didn't print my response structure`. Don't undestand. The php script echos some json text. That text you will receive of course.